# xcode breakpoints not stopping at correct line

Tags: c++, xcode, breakpoints

[image]

As shown above, the program stop at correct line. Also the first three breakpoints (1.1, 2.1, 3.1) are triggered at same time. Does anybody have idea about it? Thanks a lot.

Here is my build configuration

[image]

and optimization level is set to None. But Xcode version is 8.2.1

Comment: clean and rebuild, then compile may result right breakpoint

Comment: I did. But still same

Comment: one more try, in finder press SHIFT+Command+G and type   ~/LibraryDeveloper/Xcode/DerivedData/     then delete all contents inside DerivedData folder. Then compile.

Comment: Never put enter or remove empty lines, while you put breakpoints in your code. You will not get breakpoint at correct line. Remove all breakpoints and add again.

Comment: I tried both. but still not working.